# Determining speed of PCI Express

Tags: hardware, supermicro, pci-express

I am trying to use a new NIC in my server however I am getting this message,

"This Solarflare Network Adapter requires the equivalent of 8 lanes at PCI Express 2 speed for full throughput"

I have the motherboard at,
http://www.supermicro.com/Aplus/motherboard/Opteron2000/MCP55/h8dme-2.cfm

However I can't find the PCI Express version is it 1 or 2? I suspect 1 but I want to be sure before I buy a new motherboard. Thanks.

Comment: From the specifications it's highly likely the board only supports PCIe v1, as v2 got common later. Also, Supermicro would note in their specifications if it was v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the manual doesn't say anything about PCIE 2.0 it is almost certainly v1 PCI-E.

The speeds of 2.0 ports are double the speed.  Though the card should work in those slots it may not have enough bandwidth to fully utilize it.

Comment: I have a few MCP55 boards, they're PCIe 1.0